# Docker compose file configuration

Tags: postgresql, docker, redis

**Developer context**
On your project tech stack is based on Postgres, RabbitMQ and Redis. Your team regulary faces issue because of different versions of this tools. During last retrospective your team made decision resolve this problem with docker compose. There is approved list of environment variables:

```
DB_URL=postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/nodejs-db
CACHE_URL=redis://localhost:6379
BUS_URL=amqp://user:pass@localhost:5672
```

**Task:**
Create docker compose file what will include LTS version with Postgres, RabbitMQ and Redis. All services should run at the same network and be exposed on default port. Use environment variables for configuring docker containers.

my code:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      DB_URL: postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/nodejs-db$
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.16
    environment:
      CACHE_URL: redis://localhost:6379
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: "rabbitmq"
    environment:
      BUS_URL: amqp://user:pass@localhost:5672
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: admin
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: password
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
```

Comment: At a glance that Compose file seems reasonable; what's the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Probably you should make an explicit question because readers can be confused about what's the problem here (if any).

Have you tried to run those containers? Are there any errors while `docker-compose up`? Does the containers remain up and active after a while? Do they log any messages?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.